# List network SSID only

Tags: networking, 20.04, nmcli

I need to get all nearby network SSIDs. I'm using:

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Which works great!

But I need **just** the SSIDs for printing in an app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nmcli` provides the `-f <field, ...>` option to specify columns.

So here, it would be

```
nmcli -f SSID device wifi list
```

If you want to cut off the SSID header, you can then pipe the result through `sed -n '1!p'`, to remove the first line of output, like so

```
nmcli -f SSID device wifi list | sed -n '1!p'
```